# reaching value from main function

Tags: python

Good evening. Im having problem with my function. I have a menu with 4 or 5 different
choices and i want to call my Usermeny() from main and make an if, elif statement so that
if Choice == 1: do something.

But when i choose 1 i get this error "NameError: global name 'Choice' is not defined"

If i add global Choice in my Usermeny function i can call it from main but i thought my return would work?

in my main function it looks like this

```
def main():

    TRIES=25
    Usermeny()

    if Choice==1:
        DOSOMETHNIGHERE
```

And user menu looks like this

```
def Usermeny():

    while True:
        try:
            global Choice
            Choice=(int(input("What would you like to do: ")))

        except ValueError:
            print("You have to choose a number in the meny")
            continue

        if not Choice in range(1,5):
            print("You have to choose a number in the meny")
            continue

        return Choice
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the code you provided... While the solution is almost certainly already posted below, perhaps if you can post an example of code which actually demonstrates the problem, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: also, `choice < 1 or choice >= 5`  is bound to be more efficient than `not choice in range(1,5)`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the global declaration, it's not needed.

Assign the result of the `Usermeny` function to `Choice` in the main function:

```
def main():
    TRIES=25
    Choice = Usermeny()

    if Choice == 1:
        DOSOMETHNIGHERE
```